# MYSQL get rows inserted from today

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following code which keeps displaying 0 although rows are being inserted every day, i need it to work so that it finds what has been added today.

```
SELECT count(distinct id) AS today 
 FROM exchange 
 WHERE time >= date_sub(now(), interval 0 day)
```

Thanks

today means any time after 00:00 and format is: time();

Comment: "Today" means "last 24 hours" or "any time after `0:00` with same date as now"?

Comment: And what is `time` datatype ?

Comment: today means any time after 00:00 and format is: time();

Comment: `mysql` is not my strongest sql dialect, have you tried `..WHERE time > CURDATE() + 0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that `` `time` `` is a `timestamp` column and `id` is the Primary Key of the table (so no need to count distinct ids, just count rows):

```
SELECT count(*) AS today 
FROM exchange 
WHERE `time` >= CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in the same way as the `CURDATE` solution, by starting a day from 12:00 AM midnight rather than the first 24 hours:

```
select count(*) from <table> where date(<date_column>)=date(now());
```