# how to get today inserted row in mysql table

Tags: java, mysql

I have a MySQL database in that a table storing row with the DateTime data type column.

```
int todayuser=0;
  try{
      Connection con = (Connection)session.getAttribute("connection");
      Statement smt = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs= smt.executeQuery("SELECT * from user_information where signup_date = CURDATE()");

      while(rs.next()){
          HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
          map.put("userid", rs.getString("userid"));
          map.put("name", rs.getString("name"));
          map.put("email", rs.getString("email"));
          map.put("signup_date", rs.getString("signup_date"));

          allrequestlist.add(map);
          todayuser = allrequestlist.size();
      }
}
catch(Exception e){       
   out.println(e);       
}
```

Now, I want to get the total row stored today. CURDATE() also have yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS:

Comment: Have a look at this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705955/mysql-get-rows-inserted-from-today

Comment: @tim Biegeleisen that map work fine with the other query.

Comment: `today date also contains date and time` <-- what does this mean?

Comment: @MaxMustermann I tried that that one also but I didn't get

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen today date also contains date and time means DateTime formate

Comment: If I understand your issue correctly, you're comparing two different formats `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss = YYYY-MM-DD`, you can try changing it to `signup_date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`. Edit: the link above is actually a better solution :)

Comment: Your signup_date also contains a time portion, so it will never match if you compare it just to a date. You'll need to use the greater then operator to match everything as of today 00:00h and later. If the solution from Max isn't working, can you please indicate what's going wrong exactly or what you're output is?

Comment: @pepper thanks for your suggestion  but I didn't get result

Comment: @TheWhiteRabbit I am not getting any output or exception also

Comment: I tried this also PreparedStatement smt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from user_information where singup_date =?");
            smt.setDate(1, newDate());
            ResultSet rs= smt.executeQuery();

Comment: That's weird, don't think `CURDATE()` is supposed to have hh:mm:ss, you can maybe try to put it inside a `DATE()` to remove them? Like so: `signup_date >= DATE(CURDATE())`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Now() function of MySQL.